# Forward declarations that involve std::vector, etc

Tags: c++, c++11, forward-declaration, std

I have used forward declarations a lot; they help avoid many `#include`s, improve compilation time and what not. But what if i want to forward-declare a class in the standard library?

```
// Prototype of my function - i don't want to include <vector> to declare it!
int DoStuff(const std::vector<int>& thingies);
```

I have heard it's forbidden/impossible to forward-declare `std::vector`. Now [this answer to an unrelated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824646/how-to-stop-propagating-declarations-through-hierarchical-includes/7873493#7873493) suggests to rewrite my code this way:

**stuff.h**

```
class VectorOfNumbers; // this class acts like std::vector<int>
int DoStuff(const VectorOfNumbers& thingies);
```

**stuff.cpp**

```
// Implementation, in some other file
#include <vector>
class VectorOfNumbers: public std::vector<int>
{
    // Define the constructors - annoying in C++03, easy in C++11
};

int DoStuff(const VectorOfNumbers& thingies)
{
    ...
}
```

Now, if i use `VectorOfNumbers` instead of `std::vector<int>` in all contexts throughout my project, everything is going to be good, and i don't need to `#include <vector>` in my header files anymore!

Does this technique have major disadvantages? Can the gain of being able to forward-declare `vector` outweigh them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason I wouldn't do this:

```
const std::vector<int>& a = a_3rd_party_lib::get_data(); // this type is out of your control
DoStuff(a); // you cannot pass it to this function!
```

Comment: Couldn't VectorOfNumbers just trivially provide a conversion ctor from it's underlying std::vector type?

Comment: @Martin: It would copy the whole thing. You don't want this, do you?

Answer (score 6):

If you ever delete a `VectorOfNumbers` as a `std::vector<int>` (and since you used public inheritance this conversion is implicit) you've entered the realm of undefined behavior. This is probably more likely to accidentally happen than one might suspect.

I've never personally noticed significant compilation slowdown from just including `vector` where needed, but if you really want to isolate the include, use a client API interface that doesn't know about the underlying container type (`vector`) and pimpl the `vector` include into a single source file.

Answer (score 0):

You include `<vector>` in your header file. The `<vector>` header will have been built to prevent multiple inclusions, so you just include it everywhere you need it.

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question?

Answer (score 0):

This works well for the interface for a class, but not for the implementation. If your class has any `vector` members you must `#include <vector>` or the class definition will not compile.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inheritance, you could use composition:

```
// Implementation, in some other file
#include <vector>
class VectorOfNumbers
{
    public:

    std::vector<int>& container;

    VectorOfNumbers(std::vector<int>& in_container)
        : container(in_container)
    {
    }
};

int DoStuff(const VectorOfNumbers& thingies)
{
    std::sort(thingies.container.begin(), thingies.container.end());
    // ...
}
```

The downside is the extra variable name on every access.

Also, you'd need this implementation to be in a header file included by cpps so they will know what they can do with VectorOfNumbers.

Essentially, just making a wrapper for your vector. This is like a light-weight version of [PImpl](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) (we only care about avoiding header dependencies so we don't need the full pointer decoupling). It avoids the issues raised by Mark B and ybungalobill.

But I don't think it's really worth it.